# Did Ducktales actually ever rewrite history?

Tags: time-travel, ducktales

The Ducktales Song (C'mon, sing it with me)

> Life is like a hurricane
>
> Here in Duckburg
>
> Race cars, lasers, aeroplanes
>
> It's a duck-blur!
>
> Might solve a mystery
>
> Or **rewrite history**!

Did Ducktales ever actually rewrite history? I know they time traveled; I'm wondering if they ever changed something in the past which directly influenced the future (a la Day of The Tentacle or Cursed Child).

Comment: I think part of the implications is that by discovering previously unknown artifacts, the ducks are invaliding previous historical theories.  Thus rewriting history, rather than literally time-traveling.  At least that's what I think of when I consider an archeologist to be rewriting history.

Comment: TheAsh - Which DuckTales are you talking about?  DuckTaies (1987-1990) or DuckTales (2017-)?   When there are two series with the same title, you should specify which one you are asking about to avoid possible down votes for ambiguous questions.  Never having seen the 1987-1990 DuckTales I can only agree that the comment by Mark Rogers makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @MarkRogers Agreed. Thats why I asked specifically regarding this sort of rewritng history.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: since (this part of) the theme song is identical between the two series, I'd say answers referring to either would be acceptable.

Comment: There is an episode in the original Season 1 called "Sir Gyro-de-Gearloose" where the boys and Gyro travel to medieval times and Gyro leaves gadgets and inventions in the past

Comment: @NKCampbell I considered that episode first, as well as the one where Magika and Scrooge go hopping through time, but aside from the possible step on a mosquito variety, we never actually see in those adventures history being changed. Traveled to and interacted with, yes. But nothing modern day which was changed as a result of actions in the past. At least as far as memory and a cursory wiki search reveal. Which indicates that Ducktales follows two different time travel theories, one where time travel already affected the past so nothing changes, and one where time travel can change the future

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[Season 2, Episode 1](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Time_is_Money) "Time is Money" or as many think of it- the first Bubba Duck episode. Scrooge and the boys travel back to prehistoric times, where Scrooge uses his laser pen to graffiti the walls with his initials. We know that those initials didn't exist uptime, so Scrooge has clearly intended to rewrite history such that he is now owner of the land.

Comment: O_O Wow, never got so many votes so fast.

Comment: Disney cartoons are serious business 'round these parts.

Answer (score 13):

### For DuckTales 2017 (which has the same theme song):

I would not be until the second season that time travel would be done in the 2017 series, in the episode Timephone.

However in the pilot episode, after Scrooge McDuck announces his discovery, a reporter say that Scrooge McDuck is back to "solving mysteries, and rewriting history", which may indicate that "rewriting history" does not actually mean to *change* history via time travel, but to rewrite historical records through new discoveries.

<sup>(Full episode posted by the official Disney XD channel to promote the show)</sup>

> Reclusive adventure capitalist Scrooge McDuck is back, solving mysteries, and rewriting history!

Comment: Posting a full episode of a Walt Disney property is likely a copyright violation. Also, YouTube says the video is not available in my country.

Comment: @Philipp Disney posted it themselves to promote the show (it's one of their official channels), so it should not be an issue.

Comment: at some point, the episode will likely go away. Maybe better to enable captions and take a screenshot that would be more permanent for the answer

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Ducktales now has a time-travel episode: Timephoon. Care to update your answer? If not, I'll write my own.