# What is the cartoon show played in Black Widow?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

I'm not entirely sure but I believe it's the classic *DuckTales* cartoon from the late 80s. Which episode is it and does it hold a meaning for the movie?

Comment: Probably that one episode where Dewey and Louie are kidnapped and trained as assassins, and Louie is a bit resentful when Dewey murders a child to defect but doesn't get Louie out too. DuckTales, woo-ooo.

Comment: (Spoilers for DuckTales.)

Comment: I'd say the only meaning is it is also owned by Disney and was wildly successful for the time.  Moonraker on the otherhand is almost certainly meant to foreshadow the end of the movie where the super villain base in the sky gets destroyed James Bond style.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Stop rewriting history. [Oh, wait...](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177411/did-ducktales-actually-ever-rewrite-history)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All the clips are actually from the intro for season 1 of the original *DuckTales*. The clips that follow prove this point.

The first time we see them watching it is in Ohio on the TV in the background.

[image: Alexei walks past the TV showing Magica on the TV]

The episode here is season 1 episode 6, "Send in the Clones". This episode has clear parallels to *Black Widow* in that the family are a sleeper cell at the start of the film. On top of that, as revealed later in the film, there are Widows as sleepers all over the world. To an extent the Widows themselves, stripped of free will, are clones of each other as well.

> Everyone begins seeing double when Magica DeSpell gets the Beagle Boys to help her steal the Number One Dime, disguising them as replace the nephews. Can the nephews expose them before the dime is stolen (and before Mrs. Beakley loses her mind)?
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, List of *DuckTales* episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DuckTales_episodes)</sub>

[image: Magica holds Poe and laughs]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

As part of this sequence we see the intro clip over to the next scene. This appears to be an intro only clip.

[image: Scrooge and Huey battling the Beagle Boys in a bakery]

The second time we see them watching it is when we see Nat being forced to watch it. Presumably to help if she needs to go undercover again.

[image: Nat watches DuckTales alongside other Widow recruits]

Again as far as I can tell this particular clip is from the intro only.

[image: Underwater Webby kisses the shark chasing them]

Comment: Bruce's expression looked a bit like that shark's when Nat started flirting with him in *Age of Ultron*.

Comment: Ironically, Duck Tales were one of the 4 Disney cartoons they licensed and translated into Russian and showed on Russian TV around 1990. So she could have watched it in Russia without going to all the suffering of moving to Ohio.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To: Right...that's why they were in Ohio... :P